# Does Rails use (compromised) MD5 for sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

Does Ruby on Rails internally make use of the MD5 cryptographic hash function, specifically for sessions?

The [Ruby on Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-id) states that:

> The **session id is a 32 byte long MD5 hash value**. A session id consists of the hash value of a random string. The random string is the current time, a random number between 0 and 1, the process id number of the Ruby interpreter (also basically a random number) and a constant string. Currently it is not feasible to brute-force Rails' session ids. **To date MD5 is uncompromised**, but there have been collisions, so it is theoretically possible to create another input text with the same hash value. But this has had no security impact to date.

However, it's common knowledge that MD5 is indeed compromised. Eg. [Wikipedia:MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security) states:

> The security of the MD5 hash function is **severely compromised**. A collision attack exists that can find collisions within seconds ...

Have I misunderstood, or is [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) in fact just the w3schools of Rails?

Comment: Note: Not on [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com/) as the question isn't about whether MD5 is deprecated - it's about the usage in this programming scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this section of guide was updated in https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/25035 after https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25032 was reported.

---

Bits of that guide are very out of date (eg the xss section hasn't caught up with the fact that rails considers all strings as needing escaping unless told otherwise) - it could certainly do with some love. It looks like that section hasn't been touched since at least 2009

Rails hasn't used the method you describe for generating session ids for a long time. If I'm reading the runes correctly, since rails 2.3 the session id has been generated with `SecureRandom` which provides cryptographically secure random numbers (either using Ruby's builtin support on 1.8.7, or using platform specific methods such as openssl, /dev/urandom, win32 apis)

In addition since rails 2.0, the default session store has been the cookie store which doesn't use session id in the first place (or rather the value of the session cookie *is* the session, rather than a key used to read the session from elsewhere)

Comment: I reported this documentation problem as https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25032